Solution to wave equation on a cylinder
In many texts, it is claimed that the most general solution to the wave equation
$$(\partial_{\tau}^2-\partial^{2}_{\sigma} )X(\sigma,\tau) = 0$$
where $(\sigma,\tau) \in S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$  is as usual a sum of a left and right moving piece
$$X_L(\sigma^+)+X_R (\sigma^-)$$
where $\sigma^{\pm} = \tau \pm \sigma$
and $X_{L/R}$ are arbitrary functions.
However, it is claimed any we also have Fourier expansions
$$X_L(\sigma^+) = 
\frac{1}{2} x + p\sigma^+ + i \sum_{n \neq 0} \frac{1}{n} \tilde{\alpha}_n e^{-in\sigma^+}$$
$$X_R(\sigma^-) = 
\frac{1}{2} x + p\sigma^- + i \sum_{n \neq 0} \frac{1}{n} \alpha_n e^{-in\sigma^-}$$
for some constants $x$ and $p$.
How can these claims be justified: namely the linear parts of these expansions and the fact that the "Fourier coefficients" are divided by $n$ are unusual.

First, you need to exclude $n=0$ from the sums. Then rescaling $\alpha_n$ by $n$ gets rid of the $n$ in the denominator, so it’s just a choice. Finally, the $n=0$ piece is captured by the $x$ and $p$ terms. What’s the confusion?

Right - I'm okay accepting that the alpha n are rescalings of normal Fourier coefficients so that the commutation relations come out cleanly. However, I still don't follow why the n = 0 term is what it is.

Consider a simpler example first: $y’’=0$. It’s a second order linear differential equation so the solutions are exponentials. But the roots of characteristic polynomial are both $0$. In such cases, $x$ times an exponential is also a solution, so the general solution is $a + bx$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants. This is what’s happening here.

Thinking more about this, I think I understand what your question is. The solution should have the same value at $\sigma=0$ and $\sigma=2\pi$. Indeed, the full solution is independent of $p$ so there’s no contradiction.
